# Stack Exchange notifications on Facebook?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, notifications, facebook

I don't know if this already exists or not, but is there an app on Facebook to send me notifications from Stack Exchange?

If it doesn't exist, I think it would be very cool and useful to receive the notifications of answer and comments on Facebook.

Comment: You might try looking on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com).