# Can I associate my SE account to Facebook to get notifications?

Tags: support, notifications, facebook

I tried using the "my logins" button in the user page but it didn't do anything. Is this feature available?

Comment: What made you assume it was available?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn It was unusual to see login options when I'm already signed in. I figured it could have some useful features.

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible.

Stack Exchange only uses your Facebook account to authenticate you and to populate your name and avatar if you don't otherwise specify them. There is no further integration with Facebook, such as notifications.

There is [an existing feature request asking that Stack Exchange add notifications through Facebook](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107545/stack-exchange-notifications-on-facebook), but it has never had much support or an official response. When it was first suggested I had an idea for how users might achieve this without support from Stack Exchange:

> If you sign up for email notifications with your `@facebook.com` email address, you'd be notified if you were in Facebook. Unfortunately that isn't sent out too frequently...

Sadly, I was mistaken and this does not work. Emails like this get filtered into your "Other" messages folder and you are not notified of them.

Facebook does not make a very good general-purpose email service.

Comment: Oh goodie. Thanks for the link, I had missed downvoting that one.